# New to Drupal 7: Trying to figure out CSS

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I inherited an already built Drupal 7 site. I have been able to figure out many things. But I am unclear on the CSS. A found a folder full of long-named CSS files but the code is all minified and hard to read. The previous developer had to be using some tools or services to alter and change the code in a more readable way. Does any know what the deal is ?

Also, I cant seem to find any way inside Drupal to enter CSS. I do not even see any classes or ID assigned to the blocks, views, nodes, or fields. So I have no clue how they were able to customize this site at all even though they obviously did. It uses Bootstrap 3 as a theme. Can anyone help explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to figure out the essence of the informations you given.

First: You have a Drupal 7 installation with  compressed css files based on Bootstrap. That sounds the theme use less or sass precompiler for the theme css and  you have the production (builded) instance of the project. Without the uncompressed less/sass/scss files it will be hard to edit the css. if you have no way to get the source files, the best way you can try is to add a extra css file and write you own css in it.

Second: Drupal strictly separates the code from the administration interface. Your PHP, HTML, CSS and other codes (except the WYSIWYG output) should not be entered via the administration interface. That's the best practice way. But anyway, there is a couple of modules that allows to write code inside the Drupal backend like this https://www.drupal.org/project/extra_css_js

Third: As information for you, Drupal 7s End of life is on November 28, 2022 so the best and recommanded way for you is: Freeze the Drupal 7s Instance as is (only Sercurity Updates and Hotfixes) and relaunch the Project with Drupal 9.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal theme css files are mostly located in theme folder like "theme folder/css/style.css". As above mentioned, it might be used css minify tool or module for theme performance aspects. If it is created by drupal tools/module then once cache clear it will delete automatically and regenerate with new one with updated new css code on after page visit. You can also add custom css file by hook alter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).